# Tableau join tables

Tags: tableau-api

[image]

What's the difference between the vertical alignment (orange box) and the horizontal alignment (blue box)?

Let's say all the joins are inner joins. Does it mean:

`Orders JOIN (Orders1 JOIN People JOIN Returns) JOIN People1`?

Answer (score 0):

See my answer on another similar question.  It may mean

```
((ORDERS JOIN (PEOPLE JOIN PEOPLE1)) JOIN ORDERS1) JOIN RETURNS

or equivalently

((ORDERS JOIN (PEOPLE JOIN PEOPLE1)) JOIN RETURNS) JOIN ORDERS1
```

The last two joins, though on the result of parenthesis, yet are on some field(s) from ORDERS table and thus their order doesn't matter.